# Capture iOS 3D Touch cursor

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, 3dtouch

In iOS when you 3D Touch on the iPhone keyboard it allows for moving the cursor around the text field. I would like to build a text field from scratch and have similar feature. Is it possible to capture this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement the [UITextInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput) protocol, these messages will give you the info about the "floating cursor" events:

```
func beginFloatingCursor(at: CGPoint)
```

Called at the beginning of the gesture that the system uses to manipulate the cursor.

```
func updateFloatingCursor(at: CGPoint)
```

Called to move the floating cursor to a new location.

```
func endFloatingCursor()
```

Called at the end of the gesture that the system uses to manipulate the cursor